# i don't understand the code : result = quote123(func(x int) string { return fmt.Sprintf("%b", x) })

Tags: go

i am learning golang, for a code that passing a function as a parameter for another function, i don't know the meaning of the code i listed

for the quote123 function , it takes a function as the parameter, how can the part: func(x int) string { return fmt.Sprintf("%b", x) } being passed into the quote123 function, even that works, should that part return a string, this string shouldn't be the parameter for the function quote123

```
// convert types take an int and return a string value.
type convert func(int) string

// value implements convert, returning x as string.
func value(x int) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v", x)
}

// quote123 passes 123 to convert func and returns quoted string.
func quote123(fn convert) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%q", fn(123))
}

func main() {
    var result string

    result = value(123)
    fmt.Println(result)
    // Output: 123

    result = quote123(value)
    fmt.Println(result)
    // Output: "123"

    result = quote123(func(x int) string { return fmt.Sprintf("%b", x) })
    fmt.Println(result)
    // Output: "1111011"

    foo := func(x int) string { return "foo" }
    result = quote123(foo)
    fmt.Println(result)
    // Output: "foo"

    _ = convert(foo) // confirm foo satisfies convert at runtime
    // fails due to argument type
    // _ = convert(func(x float64) string { return "" })
}
```

Comment: Start with the Tour of Go. Now. Do the exercises. Repeat the Tour. Then go back to that problem.

Comment: Are you asking what a [function literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals) is?

Comment: i want to know how the quote123 can accept func(x int) string { return fmt.Sprintf("%b", x) } as its parameter ,and how it generates the final result 1111011

Comment: @crazyA: it's a function literal that matches the signature of `convert`. It generates `1111011` because that what it returns. I'm not sure how to expand on that. Can you be more specific about what you don't understand?

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`quote123` accepts any function that takes an integer argument and returns a string.  The argument passed to it in this code is a function literal, also known as an enclosure or an anonymous function, with this signature.  The function literal has two parts:

`func(x int) string`

This is the signature of the functional literal.  This shows you that it matches the argument type taken by `quote123`, which is the type `convert`, a named type defined as `type convert func(int) string`

`{ return fmt.Sprintf("%b", x) }`

This is the body, or implementation, of the function literal.  This is the code actually run when the function literal is called.  In this case, it takes the integer `x`, formats it in binary (that's what the `%b` formatting verb does) as a string, and returns that string.

`quote123` takes this function as an argument, calls it with an integer (in this case, the integer `123`), then takes the string return by it and formats it using the `%q` formatting verb, which surrounds the given strings in quotations.

The net effect of this is 123 is passed in, formatted as binary (`1111011`), returned as a string (`1111011`), then formatted again with surrounding quotes (`"1111011"`) which is then ultimately printed out to console.

Accepting a function literal like this allows you to customize behavior when calling a function.  `quote123` will always return a quoted string, but what's in that can change.  For example, if I instead gave it the following literal:

`func(x int) string { return fmt.Sprintf("%06d", x) }`

I would get back the string `"000123"`, because the formatting verb `%06d` says to print it as an integer, with width 6, and pad it with 0's instead of space characters.  If I instead used:

`func(x int) string { return "hello world" }`

I would always get back the string `"hello world"`, regardless of which integer it was called with.

Comment: func quote123(fn convert) string {....}          does this mean that quote123 is a function accept a function as a parameter and return a string as, how do i know the function as the parameter need to be a function return string?

Comment: The type `convert` is a function that takes an integer and returns a string.  `quote123` accepts a convert, so it accepts any function with that signature (`func(int) string`).  `quote123` _also_ returns a string, which is why `quote123` has `string` at the end of its signature as well.  `quote123`'s signature is `func(convert) string`, but could just as easily be written as `func(func(int) string) string`.  Everything inside the outer `( )` is the argument list, in this case, the single function it takes as an argument.  The whole `func(int) string` is the type of that single argument.

Comment: I think you meant "[closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))", not "enclosure". But this isn't an example of a closure, since there is no variable being closed over.